# only run javascript function after certain date

Tags: javascript

I've got some code for a daily countdown timer which counts down to 12 noon every day. I want to exclude weekends which I've done like this:

```
if((t.total<=0) || (day === 0) || (day === 6)){
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
                document.getElementById('deadline_Container').style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

However, I also need to do this for a certain date, so that the countdown won't show between 20.12. to 27.12. for example. Not sure how to do this for a specific date?

This is my whole code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var today = new Date(new Date().getTime());
    var deadline = new Date(Date.UTC(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 11, 59, 59));
    function time_remaining(endtime){
        var t = endtime - new Date();
        var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
        var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
        var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        return {'total':t, 'hours':hours, 'minutes':minutes, 'seconds':seconds};
    }
    function run_clock(id,endtime){
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        if (null === clock) {
            return;
        }
        var hours_span = clock.querySelector('.hours');
        var minutes_span = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
        var seconds_span = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

        function update_clock(){
            var t = time_remaining(endtime);
            hours_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
            minutes_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
            seconds_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
            day = today.getDay();
            if((t.total<=0) || (day === 0) || (day === 6)){
                clearInterval(timeinterval);
                document.getElementById('deadline_Container').style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        update_clock();
        var timeinterval = setInterval(update_clock,1000);
    }
    run_clock('clockdiv',deadline);
</script>

 <div id="deadline_Container">
        <div id="clockdiv">
          <!-- <div><span class="days"></span><span  class="smalltext">Days</span></div> -->
            <div><span class="hours"></span><span  class="smalltext">Hours</span></div>
            <div><span class="minutes"></span><span  class="smalltext">Minutes</span></div>
            <div class="clockLast"><span class="seconds"></span><span  class="smalltext">Seconds</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an extended condition to check the day and the month:

```
const dayOfMonth = today.getDate();
const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
if ((t.total <= 0) || (day === 0) || (day === 6) || (dayOfMonth >= 20 && dayOfMonth <= 27 && month == 12)) {
    ...
```

The full code would be:

```js
var today = new Date(new Date().getTime());
var deadline = new Date(Date.UTC(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), 11, 59, 59));

function time_remaining(endtime) {
  var t = endtime - new Date();
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  return {
    'total': t,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function run_clock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  if (null === clock) {
    return;
  }
  var hours_span = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutes_span = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var seconds_span = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function update_clock() {
    var t = time_remaining(endtime);
    hours_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutes_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    seconds_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    day = today.getDay();
    const dayOfMonth = today.getDate();
    const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
    if ((t.total <= 0) || (day === 0) || (day === 6) || (dayOfMonth >= 20 && dayOfMonth <= 27 && month === 12)) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      document.getElementById('deadline_Container').style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  update_clock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(update_clock, 1000);
}
run_clock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv">
  <span class="hours"></span>
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if one date is between two other, use *bigger than* and *smaller than*:

```
if(firstDate < actualDate && lastDate > actualDate){
    //your code
}
```

To check only one, you can use [.getTime()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) or [.valueOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_valueof_date.asp) and compare them:

```
comparableDate.getTime() == actualDate.getTime()
comparableDate.valueOf() == actualDate.valueOf()
```

If you only need to compare the date(not the time) I think [.setHours(hour, min, sec, milisec)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp) would be helpful:

```
var dateWithoutTime = actualDate;
dateWithoutTime.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```